# What is the Maximum Limit of Display Column in Obout Grid Control?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, grid, obout

My Problem related to Obout Grid is  that I have to display more than 250 Column in grid.
& i am getting error[image]

If i display around 100 columns its running well & display all records. Can any one tell what is limit of records that we can display in Grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I got Solution,

This is a limitation of the standard Unit class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit.pixel.aspx
"The Unit class can represent values only between -32768 and 32767."

So you need to make sure that the sum of all the columns' widths is smaller than 32767.
The default width of a Column is 175px, so if you auto generate the columns you will be able to use up to 187 columns.

If the columns are auto generated, you can reduce the width of the columns using the ColumnsCreated event:
http://www.obout.com/grid/aspnet_events_columns.aspx

If the columns are manually defined using the Columns collection simply set a smaller width for some of them.

reference from blog: http://www.aspbucket.com/2015/11/what-is-maximum-limit-of-display-column.html